# Oracle 11g: How I get best value of each step when I don't have all steps

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to select the best percentage for each step between 2 lists. However, as the example shows, I might not have all steps in both lists.

Given that I have the following lists of values in a table:

```
LIST_NUMBER     MAX_POINTS      PERCENTAGE
------------------------------------------
          1             79             20%
          1            150             25%
          1           9999             30%


LIST_NUMBER     MAX_POINTS      PERCENTAGE
------------------------------------------
          2             79             20%
          2           9999             35%
```

If I get `MAX(PERCENTAGE)` `GROUP BY MAX_POINTS`, I will get the following results:

```
SELECT MAX_POINTS,
  MAX (PERCENTAGE)
   FROM MY_TABLE
  GROUP MAX_POINTS
  ORDER BY MAX_POINTS ;


MAX_POINTS   MAX(PERCENTAGE)
----------------------------
        79               20
       150               25
     99999               35
```

This is not right because the second list says I should have 35% anytime I get 80+ points.
What I expect as a result is something like this:

```
MAX_POINTS   MAX(PERCENTAGE)
----------------------------
        79               20
       150               35
     99999               35
```

I can list all the `MAX_POINTS` that I could have (with both lists) and the PERCENTAGE of each step `(MAX_POINTS)` but I would get NULL at `MAX_POINTS = 15` of `LIST_NUMBER = 2`

```
LIST_NUMBER      MAX_POINTS      MAX(PERCENTAGE)
------------------------------------------------
          1           79                     20%
          1           150                    25%
          1           99999                  30%
          2           79                     20%
          2           150                   NULL <- This value should be the next non-null value of the LIST_NUMBER = 2 = 35%
          2           99999                  35%
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
select l.list_number, p.max_points,
       coalesce(t.value,
                lead(t.value ignore nulls) over (partition by l.list_number or by p.max_points)
               ) as value
from (select distinct list_number from t) l cross join
     (select distinct max_points from t) p left join
     t
     on t.list_number = l.list_number and t.max_points = p.max_points;
```

The `cross join` generates all the rows -- all lists and all `max_points`.  The `lead()` gets the next non-`NULL` value, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

With only two list first perform a **full outer join** of the two lists on the `MAX_POINT`column.

```
select 
nvl(a.MAX_POINTS,b.MAX_POINTS) MAX_POINTS, a.PERCENTAGE PERCENTAGE1, b.PERCENTAGE PERCENTAGE2
from (select MAX_POINTS,  PERCENTAGE from my_lst where LIST_NUMBER = 1) a
full outer join (select MAX_POINTS,  PERCENTAGE from my_lst where LIST_NUMBER = 2) b 
on a.MAX_POINTS = b.MAX_POINTS
;

MAX_POINTS PERCENTAGE1 PERCENTAGE2
---------- ----------- -----------
        79          20          20 
       150          25             
      9999          30          35
```

Now you have a unique list of all `MAX_POINT`s from both list along with the known percentages.

In the next step you must fill the missing percentages in both lists (the NULLs in the `PERCENTAGE1` and `PERCENTAGE` columns). Use the analytic `MIN`function with descendent ordering.

```
with step1 as (      
select 
nvl(a.MAX_POINTS,b.MAX_POINTS) MAX_POINTS, a.PERCENTAGE PERCENTAGE1, b.PERCENTAGE PERCENTAGE2
from (select MAX_POINTS,  PERCENTAGE from my_lst where LIST_NUMBER = 1) a
full outer join (select MAX_POINTS,  PERCENTAGE from my_lst where LIST_NUMBER = 2) b 
on a.MAX_POINTS = b.MAX_POINTS)
select 
MAX_POINTS, 
min(PERCENTAGE1) over (order by MAX_POINTS desc) PERCENTAGE1, 
min(PERCENTAGE2) over (order by MAX_POINTS desc) PERCENTAGE2 
from step1
order by MAX_POINTS
;

MAX_POINTS PERCENTAGE1 PERCENTAGE2
---------- ----------- -----------
        79          20          20 
       150          25          35 
      9999          30          35
```

In the last step you need only to get the highest percentage for each POINT - the `GREATEST`function do it for you:

```
with step1 as (      
select 
nvl(a.MAX_POINTS,b.MAX_POINTS) MAX_POINTS, a.PERCENTAGE PERCENTAGE1, b.PERCENTAGE PERCENTAGE2
from (select MAX_POINTS,  PERCENTAGE from my_lst where LIST_NUMBER = 1) a
full outer join (select MAX_POINTS,  PERCENTAGE from my_lst where LIST_NUMBER = 2) b 
on a.MAX_POINTS = b.MAX_POINTS),
step2 as (
select 
MAX_POINTS, 
min(PERCENTAGE1) over (order by MAX_POINTS desc) PERCENTAGE1, 
min(PERCENTAGE2) over (order by MAX_POINTS desc) PERCENTAGE2 
from step1)
select MAX_POINTS, 
GREATEST(PERCENTAGE1,PERCENTAGE2) PERCENTAGE
from step2
order by MAX_POINTS;   

MAX_POINTS PERCENTAGE
---------- ----------
        79         20 
       150         35 
      9999         35
```